# Wrong answer for Upwork C++ Test

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following question is part of the C++ Test on Upwork.

> ```
> class A {
>     typedef int I; // private member
>     I f();
>     friend I g(I);
>     static I x;
> };
> ```
>
> which of the following are valid:
>
> 1) `A::I A::f() { return 0; }`
>
> 2) `A::I g(A::I p = A::x);`
>
> 3) `A::I g(A::I p) { return 0; }`
>
> 4) `A::I A::x = 0;`

Seems to me that all answers are valid. I tested them and they work just fine!

Am I right? or Am I missing something?

Comment: I added a semicolon after the `typedef`: I don't think the question is about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way it's written, all 4 are valid.

1. This is trivial; it's the definition of the class member function.
2. This is a function prototype for a function `g`. Requires the `friend` declaration, which you have. Otherwise neither `I` nor the default value `x` are accessible to the function `g`.
3. This is the definition of the function `g`. Requires the `friend` declaration, which you have, else `I` is not accessible to the function `g`.
4. This is trivial; it's the definition of the `static` member `x`.